# How to validate dynamic radio button from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How to validate radio button if at least one in the question is not answered. If you wondered I use while loop in html to display all the questions. I'm trying the server side validation because I have no idea on how to validate in Javascript.

Sample Question Output
Do you have a fever or temperature over 38 °C? *
Yes
No
--other questions here

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" name="qid[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]"><?=$row['questions']?> *</label>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="Yes">
    <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="No">
    <label class="form-check-label" value="No">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
  if(substr($key, 0, 3) == 'ans')
  {
      $key = substr($key,4);
      // $sql2 = "INSERT INTO health_declaration (patient_id,question_id,answer) VALUES ('$patient_id','$key','$val') ";
      // $query_run1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `required` attribute to the `input` tag?

Comment: Where should I add that? I forgot that feature let me try it

Comment: `<input .... required>` Add to all input tags.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve it with your answer I'm so dumb

Comment: Last question I only add required in Yes input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### * *Moved from the comment to answer section.*

---

Add the required attribute to all input tags.

*e.g:*

```
<input type="radio" ... required>
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required*

Comment: do I need to add required in both input?

Comment: Yes. It will compare using the `name` or `id` attribute.